# How to sort 3 columns of data in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2011 on a Mac, and I need help sorting 2200 rows of data.
Basically, what I want to do is to sort the `Type` column, while keeping its corresponding data beside it after the type is shifted.

I would like all the type A's, B's, and C's to be in order, and have their adjacent data from experiment 1 and 2 follow to the new position once sorted.
Each data group is separated by a few empty rows.

Here's a small example of what my data looks like:

```
Type    EXPERIMENT 1    EXPERIMENT 2 
A            A               F            
             F               R
             S               S
             E               G

B            Y               A
             A               A
             S               H
             F  

A            A               E
             D               F
             F               S
             E 
             Y

A            F               H
             R               G
             E               A
             D               F
             Y               W
             S               E
             S

C            F               S
             D               D
             S               U
             F               J
             Y
             T
```

And this is what I want:

```
Type    EXPERIMENT 1    EXPERIMENT 2 
  A          A               F            
             F               R
             S               S
             E               G

  A          A               E
             D               F
             F               S
             E 
             Y

  A          F               H
             R               G
             E               A
             D               F
             Y               W
             S               E
             S

  B          Y               A
             A               A
             S               H
             F  

  C          F               S
             D               D
             S               U
             F               J
             Y
             T
```

Comment: It may be a good idea to show the result in addition to the input you have provided. for example, it is not clear what you mean by "type 1's, 2's, and 3's". Also, how much data do you have?

Comment: It may be a good idea to use windows

Comment: If your problem is with the blanks in the first column (type), this may help:http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/10/17/fill-blank-cells-in-a-table/

Comment: When you state ' type 1's, 2's, and 3's' do you mean ' type A's, B's, and C's'? Is the experiment data intended to be sorted as well?

Comment: Emmad Kareem, I have about 2200 rows of data, but there are empty rows in between each group of data. Some have 3 empty rows and some have only one, there isn't a whole lot of consistency in how each group is spaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an unused column to the right (aka *Helper column*) put this formula into the second row.

`=VLOOKUP("zzz",A$1:A2,1)&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,VLOOKUP("zzz",A$1:A2,1)),"0000")`

... and fill down as necessary. Select all of the columns and sort with the *Helper column* as the primary sort key. The results from your sample should mirror the following.

[image: Sorting with a helper column]

Additional formulas can be provided if you need sorting key criteria on the *Experiment x* columns. Show what you've tried together with some example of the results expected and additional assistance will no doubt be offered.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! This is exactly what I was trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it would be easy to sort if you would concatenate each data set into a row. Type goes in column A; Exp 1 into one cell in column B; Exp 2 into one cell in column C. Then the sort is simple. Otherwise you'll require a complicated macro. You can always parse it out later if required.

To concatenate you'll need to:

1. Save as new workbook first to avoid changing your original data
2. Insert a row between the headers and the first data
3. Put the formulas indicated into row 2 and copy down
4. Copy and PasteSpecial as values
5. Sort by column D
6. Delete all rows that are false

Now your sorting will be easy.

[image: Concatenation example]

Edit: fixed my formulas to line up with true column.

Comment: Thanks D_Bester, that would be another useful way to sort through my data. But I still need the data in experiment 1 and 2 to be separate and not in a single cell so that I can count how many of each letter there are. In my data, the letters in the experiment columns represent different behaviours, which I'm categorizing once all the types are sorted. But thanks for the new trick!